# What is wrong with my css? -When I link a local css file it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

So I have a client who wants their html/css/javascript turned into a wordpress.
Now I have the code downloaded for the most part on my local drive. But the css is still linked to the actual website. I tried copying and pasting the code into a new css so I would have a local copy instead, but when I do this and change the file path from the online code to my local file, certain background images that were in the css disappear. I am confused why it won't load correctly when I am using the same code they were.

Here's the client's site: http://gladhillfurniture.com

```
body {
   background:url(/custom/gladhill-furniture/images/bg.png) repeat-x 0 0;
   background-color:#eef1ea;
}

#wrapper,#catalog ul,#catalog h2,.browse h2,#ulItemTabs li a,#page-top,#page,#header-top,#header,#nav,#nav ul li,#nav a,li#search div,#footer ul,#footer ul li,#copyright,#sidebar li.widget_search {
   background:none;
}

.browse ul {
   background:url(/custom/gladhill-furniture/images/divider.gif) repeat-x 0 100%;
}

#share ul li a.email {
   background:url(/custom/gladhill-furniture/images/icons/email.gif);
}
```

Comment: Do you have those images stored locally as well?

Comment: Does the CSS file have `url()` rules which define background images, and did you _also_ download those?

Comment: Maybe show some of the CSS file you created? I'd guess references to url() as well.

Comment: Need some code to proceed. :)

Comment: Yes they are locally stored, and Michael I did just notice the css does have url rules defining the images. I'm guessing I have to write new file paths for the local drive? Or is there something else?

Comment: @NicolasFredrickson Assuming you downloaded all the necessary images, yes you need to rewrite those paths.

Comment: Here is a snippet. 
body{background:url(/custom/gladhill-furniture/images/bg.png) repeat-x 0 0;background-color:#eef1ea}#wrapper,#catalog ul,#catalog h2,.browse h2,#ulItemTabs li a,#page-top,#page,#header-top,#header,#nav,#nav ul li,#nav a,li#search div,#footer ul,#footer ul li,#copyright,#sidebar li.widget_search{background:none}.browse ul{background:url(/custom/gladhill-furniture/images/divider.gif) repeat-x 0 100%}#share ul li a.email{background:url(/custom/gladhill-furniture/images/icons/email.gif)

the file paths are correct actually to the local drive so Idk what else to think. =(

Comment: If you click the "edit" hyperlink you can add that snippet to your question. (Paste it in, then select it and click the `{}` button and it will be formatted as code.)

Comment: It's not working for me haha I'm new to this site. But I put the link to the clients site I am working on now. Again, they want it converted to wordpress so that is why I am using their code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I've put your CSS in your question for you.

Answer (score 4):

You should store those images locally and the reference paths in the css should be set to resolve the path in YOUR file system  as relative to the location of your css file - not the old file system.

Comment: Thanks guys I was overlooking my file paths, and I just had an extra / at the beginning
url(/custom/gladhill-furniture/images/buttons/go.png)
url(custom/gladhill-furniture/images/buttons/go.png)
darn touchy code haha. I didn't realize paths were not supposed to start with a /?

Comment: Paths don't necessarily need to start with a '/', but I'm glad you got it straightened out. If you check out [XPath syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp), you'll find some of the same navigation rules apply to file systems.